# rails ActiveRecord find or create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have two methods in a class one tries to find a record in the database and returns it if it exists.The second one is executed only if the first doesn't find any result, and it creates a new record with the `new` ActiveRecord method
i was suggested that I could replace both methods with only one ActiveRecord call but cant seem to find out how.

methods:

```
def find_cart_item
 @cartitem = @cart.cart_items.find_by product_id: @product.id
end

def create_cart_item
 @cartitem = @cart.cart_items.new(quantity: 0, price: @product.price, product: @product)
end
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using rails 4, you can do

```
@cart
.cart_items
.where(quantity: 0, price: @product.price, product_id: @product.id)
.first_or_initialize
```

you can also use `find_or_create` if you want to create the object in the database

If you are using rails 3 or lower , you can do

```
@cart
.cart_items
.find_or_initialize_by_quantity_and_price_and_product_id(0, @product.price, @product.id)
```

you can also use `find_or_create_by_quantity_and_price_and_product_id` if you want to create the object in the database

Comment: why not `find_or_create_by`?

Comment: @emaillenin: OP is only trying to initialize line_item

Comment: With minor modifications first answer works as i want it.thanx

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is

```
Cart.find_or_create_by(product_id: @product.id) do |c|
  c.quantity = 0 
  c.price = @product.price
end
```

See the [rails guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#find-or-create-by) for a detailed explaination.

Note that quantity should probably default to zero (to make your code cleaner) and therefore be exclude, but I have included it incase you don't have a default.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `first_or_create!` or `first_or_initialize`

```
Cart.first_or_create!(product_id: @product.id) do |ct|
  ct.quantity = 0 
  ct.price = @product.price
  ct.product_id @product.id
end
```

or

```
@cart.cart_items.where(quantity: 0, price: @product.price, product_id: @product.id)
.first_or_create!
```

And also see [this](http://blog.mitchcrowe.com/blog/2012/04/14/10-most-underused-activerecord-relation-methods/) for 10 most magical `Active Record` Queries.You would love it!